# Can you add a 99.9% column to the load test analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

In Visual Studio 2015 Web Performance and Load Test Projects you can run a load test and view the results in Load Test Analyzer. In Table View there are percentile columns for response time (90%, 95% and 99%). Is there any way to modify the load test to add configurable columns e.g. 99.9% (which is a requirement for my project and a common metric in load testing response times)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the columns offered in the load test results are fixed and so another column cannot added.

The percentile values are calculated from the data stored within the database. There are (stored) procedures within the database that do the calculations, so it should be possible for you to perform similar calculations for the required 99.9% value by writing your own SQL to access the database. The procedures can be seen via the SQL management programs. The procedures are created by the database creation code (located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\loadtestresultsrepository.sql` on my computer).  Searching for `percentile` in that file will find the code of these procedures plus many other related lines. It may be better to search for the regular expression `CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_\w*Percentile`.